# How to display data and form in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a blog and i want to display data and the submit form in the same page, i already have some code but somehow when i press the submit button the data is not being updated on the page

Here is the code in index.html.erb:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Titulo</td>
        <td>Texto</td>
    </tr>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= post.titulo %></td>
        <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>    

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :titulo, "Titulo del post" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :titulo %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :text, "Contenido" %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %><br>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Publicar"%>
    </p>
<%end%>

<%= render @posts %>
```

and this is the controller for posts:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @post = Post.new
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    private 
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:titulo, :text)
        end
end
```

now is showing all the data i created before doing this (because i used the basics of ruby like CRUD ), also i dont know if i have to do something in the "new" def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change create method to this

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

Comment: thanks,I completely forgot about that .save <3 now it works as it supposed to